# Envío fichero por correo

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una duda ahora que ya casi tengo terminado lo que quiero hacer, con esta pequeña App leo unos códigos (está instlada en una PDA con lector laser) y los guardo en un fichero, puedo enviar ese o esos ficheros por correo luego, pero he estado leyendo y creo que se podría realizar una vez creado el fichero sin necesidad de salir de la aplicación. Pero no lo tengo muy claro ni lo complejo que puede resultar.

Esta es la parte de código que tengo para recuperar la variable con el contenido del fichero que creo:

```
    String saludo = CadenaFinal; // variable para el fichero


    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Código leidos: "+contador,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


    // fecha y hora fichero //
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
    long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date curDateTime = new Date(msTime);
    // nombre fichero //
    String nombre="TRASPASO_T-"+Origen_T+" A T-"+Destino_T+"__"+ curDateTime+".csv" ;

    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(saludo);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        etOrigen.setText("");
        etNombre.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Lo que busco es que una vez creado el fichero este sea enviado a una dirección de correo electrónico (siempre sería la misma).
He encontrado en este mismo foro este código, lo he colocado a continuación del try catch que genera el fichero; no me da error pero tampoco me funciona.
Los permisos en Manifest están correctos porque probé en otro activity un envío simple de correo y funciona.

```
class SendAttachment{
    public void main(String[] args){
        //to address
        String to="in@huo.com";//change accordingly
        //from address
        final String correo="Pyt@gmail.com";//change accordingly
        final String contraseña="abcd";//change accordingly
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
        //1) get the session object
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,contraseña);
                    }
                });

        //2) compose message
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correo));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("YO");
            //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message content
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart1.setText("Mensaje Cabecera");
            //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            //Location of file to be attached
            String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/R2832.zip";//change accordingly
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName("Hola prueba");
            //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
            //6) set the multiplart object to the message object
            message.setContent(multipart );
            //7) send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Enviando Mensaje....");
        }catch (MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Prueba con JavaMail, creo que te puede ser util. Contiene las librerias para envio de datos por SMTP y similares. https://javaee.github.io/javamail/

Comment: Gracias, empezaré por ahí